# Stay in England for more than 6 months (need visa advice)

Tags: united-kingdom, relocation

Thanks in advance for any help on this topic!

So here is the situation. My wife and I are planning on going to England for 6 months to a year or so. We will be traveling to nearby countries as well here and there. I already know that you can visit the UK with no visa for up to 6 months. But we would like to stay longer and want to see if there is a way to do so.

Now here are some important factors...

- My wife is a UK citizen (has UK/US dual citizenship) but she only is a UK citizen because of her mom who was born a UK citizen. My wife was born and has lived in the US but because of her mom she gets the dual citizenship.
- We will be living with her Grandmother who has lived in England all her life.
- My wife works for an Engineering company who is allowing her to work 100% remote while she is over there. They technically have an office in England but she will be working for a project that is US based still. They decided not to "transfer" her to the UK office because she would get paid a lot less.

So I think regardless she can stay as long as she wants cause she has the dual citizenship, but we need to find a way for me to be able to stay longer.

Given the situation above, would I be able to get a spouse visa? Since she will technically be working on a US based project, will that not allow me to do that? Can she even tell immigration that she is doing that? Even though she has dual citizenship?

If that is not possible... her grandmother is 82 and is legally blind, is there some sort of caregiver visa I can get to help my wife take care of her?

Or maybe sign up for a class and get a student visa?

Just trying to figure out an option.

Thank!

- Branden

Comment: More than anything, I highly recommend against trying to make conjuring false reasons for coming to UK and presenting them as real reason for your trip. If found out you may be rejected for deception, which means that you will be highly unlikely to enter UK ever again. Also, what is your nationality?

Comment: Their decision not to transfer her may or may not be acceptable to the UK, but for sure she will be liable for UK taxes.  If she tries to live there without complying with UK requirements then you probably can't live with her legally. On the other hand, if she does pay UK taxes and so on, then you should be able to get a spouse visa, assuming you meet all the requirements. The real question is how the UK will view her being an employee of a US company when she resides in the UK.

Comment: It will probably be simplest for her to be carried on the UK office payroll, with the US project reimbursing the UK office for her salary etc. Otherwise, the US office will have to deal with a lot of unfamiliar paperwork.